# Error while setting scrapy as cron job: "scrapy: not found"

Tags: cron

I want to set a cron job, to run my scrapy (python script)

This is how I can run the script, and it runs fine:

```
ubuntu@ip-1-2-3-4-:cd /home/ubuntu/scrapers/my_scraper/
ubuntu@ip-1-2-3-4-:~/scrapers/my_scraper$ scrapy crawl my_spider
```

Now I try to run the above command as a cron job:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

added the following lines:

```
PATH=/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/
35 14 * * * cd /home/ubuntu/scrapers/my_scraper && scrapy crawl my_spider
```

This is not successful... I am also not able to diagnose the problem... if I run:

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

I get the following output:

```
Jul 12 06:47:01 ip-1-2-3-4 CRON[1451]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly ))
Jul 12 07:17:01 ip-1-2-3-4 CRON[1825]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 12 08:17:01 ip-1-2-3-4 CRON[1836]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 12 09:17:01 ip-1-2-3-4 CRON[1849]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 12 10:17:01 ip-1-2-3-4 CRON[1861]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 12 11:17:01 ip-1-2-3-4 CRON[1869]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 12 12:17:01 ip-1-2-3-4 CRON[1878]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 12 13:17:01 ip-1-2-3-4 CRON[1887]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 12 14:17:01 ip-1-2-3-4 CRON[1962]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 12 15:17:01 ip-1-2-3-4 CRON[1970]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 12 16:17:01 ip-1-2-3-4 CRON[1982]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 12 17:17:01 ip-1-2-3-4 CRON[1991]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 12 18:17:01 ip-1-2-3-4 CRON[2002]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 12 19:17:01 ip-1-2-3-4 CRON[2010]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 12 20:05:01 ip-1-2-3-4 CRON[2018]: (root) CMD (   test -x /etc/cron.daily/popularity-contest && /etc/cron.daily/popularity-contest --crond)
Jul 12 20:17:01 ip-1-2-3-4 CRON[2022]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 12 21:17:01 ip-1-2-3-4 CRON[2031]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 12 22:17:01 ip-1-2-3-4 CRON[2039]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 12 23:17:01 ip-1-2-3-4 CRON[2047]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 13 00:17:01 ip-1-2-3-4 CRON[2156]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 13 01:17:01 ip-1-2-3-4 CRON[2465]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 13 02:17:01 ip-1-2-3-4 CRON[2549]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 13 03:17:01 ip-1-2-3-4 CRON[2980]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 13 04:17:01 ip-1-2-3-4 CRON[3033]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

this is strange, because the most recent line is from 4 AM this morning (local time is 2 pm), so not sure why there is no error being logged either?

Note: `/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/` is where the scrapy is (I found it using the command `which scrapy`)

### update (time zone issue)

The reason I was not getting any error was that my time zone was wrong, after fixing the timezone, I am getting the following error:

> scrapy: not found

I also tried using run-my-scraper.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/ubuntu/scrapers/my_scraper
PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/python3
export PATH
/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/scrapy crawl my_spider
```

I tested running the above shell script from the console and it works, then I added it as a cron job, but still same result:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

added the following:

```
39 16 * * * ./home/ubuntu/scrapers/shell-scripts/run-my-scraper.sh
```

But still getting *scrapy: not found* error.

Comment: your path env var should maybe point to the python program...probably `/usr/local/bin` - I cannot test myself, that is just an idea - You can add more than 1 path to $PATH with `PATH=$PATH:/dir/one:/dir/two:/dir/ectory/4`

Comment: Thanks, I will try this

Comment: In crontab I always give the absolute path to the executable.  I don't have much luck depending on *any* declaration of $PATH. And even when your working directory contains the executable, you must path it explicitly: ` ./scrapy` The working directory is not automatically on the session search path.

Comment: @StephenBoston: thanks... I have updated the question... I tried the full path of scrapy and from a shell script, but still not successful. Not really sure how to see the error message?

Comment: In the crontab line you show us you have a leading `.` in the filepath. That starts the path from the working directory.That is probably not what you wnat. The absolute path will be `/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/scrapers/shell-scripts/run-my-scraper.sh` No leading `.`  and assuming you are still using `.local/bin` as you were at first. Make sure your script is executable.

Comment: @StephenBoston: thanks a lot... using the full path, it finally worked: `56 18 * * * cd /home/ubuntu/scrapers/my_scraper && /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/scrapy crawl my_spider`

Comment: Good news! One more thing though,you don't have to `cd` when using the full path.

Comment: @StephenBoston: thanks again for your help... just to clarify, I am not using the .sh script in the end... instead I type the commands in the crontab: [like this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258627/error-while-setting-scrapy-as-cron-job-scrapy-not-found/1258671#1258671)... I tried removing `cd`, but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

35 14 * * * cd /home/ubuntu/scrapers/my_scraper && scrapy crawl my_spider

maybe try to get rid of the **cd** command.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and cd is required...

Answer (score 1):

**in newscript.sh**
#!/bin/bash
su - ubuntu **OR** set PATH= if necessary... since you made the cronjob as sudo
cd /home/ubuntu/scrapers/my_scraper/
scrapy crawl my_spider

**the part you said worked already ^**

in crontab
35 14 * * * /home/blahblah/newscript.sh

...bottom line, make a working script, call the script in the cron job... make sure it's executable.

Comment: Thanks for this, it turned out that my timezone was wrong

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with my timezone... my server was set to UTC and I was setting the cron job with Australian time, that's why I could not see any error message.

After fixing the timezone the following worked for me (thanks to the comment from @Stephen Boston, who pointed out I need to use the full path for scrapy):

`crontab -e`

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin
56 18 * * * cd /home/ubuntu/scrapers/my_scraper && /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/scrapy crawl my_spider
```